# mysqli update query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting the following error message, something wrong with the syntax of my code apparently but I'm not sure what it is. If I change the $data to something simple like "pie" it will update. Seems to be an error with the serialized string?

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' . DB_PFIX . 'settings SET setting_options = 'a:12:{s:13:"website_title"' at line 2`

code:

```
<?php

if( !empty( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $data = serialize( array(
        'website_title' => $_POST['website_title'],
        'website_slogan' => $_POST['website_slogan'],
        'website_theme' => $_POST['website_theme'],
        'website_homepage' => $_POST['website_homepage'],
        'website_description' => $_POST['website_description'],
        'website_keywords' => $_POST['website_keywords'],
        'website_language' => $_POST['website_language'],
        'website_timezone' => $_POST['website_timezone'],
        'website_date_format' => $_POST['website_date_format'],
        'website_time_format' => $_POST['website_time_format'],
        'website_url' => $option['website_url'],
        'website_path' => $option['website_path']
    ));

    $query = '
        UPDATE
            ' . DB_PFIX . 'settings
        SET
            setting_options = "' . $data . '"
        WHERE
            setting_name = "' . $setting_name . '"
    ';

    $result = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query );

    if ( mysqli_affected_rows( $db_connect ) == 1 ) {
        echo "GOOD!";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error( $db_connect );
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `var_dump(DB_PFIX);` and show here

Comment: Bart, DB_PFIX is the table prefix I defined in my config file. Its a constant.

Comment: @CoryNickerson are you sure it is known at that point in the script? Show the definition.

Comment: yup. I vardump it and it outputs 'cms_settings'. Which is the tables name. Like I said if you edit `$data` to something simple like `$data = "pie";`, the query will execute with no error.

Comment: Can you print the executed query syntax before executing it? i.e. print the $query variable and paste it so we can check for query syntax mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put a serialized string into a database without escaping. Escape your data or use prepared statements.

Quick fix:

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
```

Real fix: use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php).

Comment: Thanks mate. Question, why does everything question I post on here get voted down?

Comment: @CoryNickerson I don't know. Read the FAQ again and try to go in lengths to solve your question, show that you have tried different things and have at least a basic understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the query string has not been interpreted properly. The constant expression `DB_PFIX` should not be visible by its name but by its value in the statement! Carefully check the variable `$query` by just echoing it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

What about to add [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) like:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($data)

mysqli_real_escape_string($settings_name);
```